# How can I know if a file system was cleanly unmounted?

Tags: filesystems, logs, shutdown, unmounting

I know, `fsck.ext4 -p /dev/whatever`, right? That seemed to be the answer, but then I read that journaling covers a multitude of sins, and the result from `fsck` will just tell you that there isn't a problem with that file system, but won't tell you that you did something dangerous, like shutdown/turning off the system with a file system mounted.

If a log could confirm it, that would be enough. I thought that might be found by looking in `journalctl` or grep'ing /var/log/*log, but I was expecting to see strings like "home" or "sda3" to confirm successful unmountings, but nothing came up to indicate that.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `extN` filesystems you can check the superblock. For example,

```
tune2fs -fl /dev/sda1 | grep '^Filesystem features:'
```

In my case, a mounted filesystem includes the word `needs_recovery` whereas a cleanly unmounted filesystem does not.

```
fs=/dev/sda1
if tune2fs -fl "$fs" | awk -F: 'BEGIN { ss=0 } $1 == "Filesystem features" && $2 ~ /needs_recovery/ { ss=1 } END { exit ss }'
then
    echo "$fs: seems ok"
else
    echo "$fs: needs recovery (fsck)"
fi
```

Comment: What's `-fl`? My man pages doesn't recognize it.

Comment: @Opux it's two options crashed together. (This is a standard UNIX feature.) Look up `-f` and `-l` as separate items and you'll find their meanings (`-f` = force, `-l` = list). Try `tune2fs -l /dev/sda1` or equivalent, i.e. without the `-f`, to see what happens when the filesystem is and is not mounted. Then repeat with the `-f`

Comment: Gotcha. I didn't realize `l` was a letter.

So why the `-f` option? That means "force" according to the man pages. I'm used to using that word in connection w/write operations.

Comment: @Opux try it and you'll see why the `-f` is required. It surprised me too

Comment: I did. And now I've done it w/out the `-f` and I see no difference. I imagine the difference comes later

Comment: Oh ok. In my case I found I couldn't use `tune2fs` on a mounted filesystem without `-f`

Comment: Oh, you waned it mounted. I didn't mount it. I thought it made more sense to check it before mounting. Is it better to mount it first?

Comment: @Opux when possible I prefer to cover every base. Technically you might say that a currently mounted filesystem has not been cleanly unmounted

Comment: Ok, I did like you said and seems to be working. But about the `-f`. Usually procedures that are called "force" are in connection with write operations, not read-only. Does any writing get done?

BTW, if I may suggest, you might prefer searching for the string "clean" instead of "needs recovery". I'm sure you'd rather a false positive when searching for problems rather than a false negative